# Count for different types (same interface) in ArrayList

Tags: java, interface, arraylist

I got 2 classes implementing same interface like this..

```
// Interface
Interface ISomething { ... }

// Class A
class A implements ISomething { ... }

// Class B
class B implements ISomething { ... }
```

then in the `ArrayList<ISomething>` I have many instances of both class A and B.

Is there a way to count for occurrences of class A and B separately without using `instanceof`. I tied many ways(such as creating new methods in both class A and B for letting them decide whether they should increase which counting variables kept in array of integers passed to them) but they seemed not to be good designs.

PS. Sorry for my English and lack of skills in both Java and OO Design. If this is a bad question please let me know.

**UPDATE**
I tried [visitor_pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) and it worked (it's more maintainable than the approach I used earlier).
The code is like this..

```
// Interfaces
Interface ISomething { public void accept(ISomethingVisitor visitor); }
Interface ISomethingVisitor {
    public void visit(A a);
    public void visit(B b);
}

// Classes
class A implements ISomething {
     @Override
     public void accept(ISomethingVisitor visitor) { visitor.visit(this); }
}
class B implements ISomething {
     @Override
     public void accept(ISomethingVisitor visitor) { visitor.visit(this); }
}
class SomethingCountVisitor implements ISomethingVisitor {
     private int aCount;
     private int bCount;

     @Override
     public void visit(A a) { aCount++; }
     @Override
     public void visit(B b) { bCount++; }
     //getters for aCount, bCount
}

// Example usage
// Assuming items have many A and B instances.
ArrayList<ISomething> items = new ArrayList<ISomething>();
...
SomethingCountVisitor scVisitor = new SomethingCountVisitor();
for (ISomething item in items)
    item.accept(scVisitor);
```

Comment: Question: why do you have a list of ISomething AND AT THE SAME TIME you need to count how many istances of each subtype are present? It seems to me that 2 lists of A and B would be better

Comment: It may be undesirable to care which class it is, but if that is what matters, instanceof is the simple, straightforward way of finding out. Why avoid it?

Comment: When adding a new element I want that it doesn't matter what the type the new element is as long as it implements ISomething. Is this a bad design?

Comment: This isn't a bad design. But WHY do you need to know the specific class?

Comment: Because I want to count for separate types. When adding a new element I don't know in advance which type it is(but it's always implementing ISomething) so I can't just increment the separate count variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `instanceof` you can only use `A.class.isInstance(Object)`

Answer (score 0):

Google's Guava has the tools for you. https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/

```
ArrayList<ISomething> myList = ...
Iterable<A> iterableOfAs = Iterables.filter(myList, A.class);
int numOfAs = Iterables.size(iterableOfAs)
```

I highly recommend using Guava for your projects. It can improve your efficiency by orders of magnitude. Adding it to your project is as simple either for jar based projects or maven manged ones.

Answer (score 0):

If you will always have only two classes, declare a method in your interface:

```
boolean isAnA();
```

Implement it to return true in class `A`, false in class `B`. Use its result to decide which counter to increment.

If there ever may be more than two classes, return an enum instead.

However, this is all rather indirect. If you really care about which class it is, instanceof is the direct, simple way to ask that question.

Comment: If your interface needs to know anything about its implementers, it's bad design.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple, NO. because Generics exists only during compile time, not run time. They are safety measures, what to add and what not to add. But once the code is compiled, there's no difference between `ArrayList` and `ArrayList<I>`.

Without counting using `instanceof`, you can't check what's there!

Comment: You answer would be true if A and B were parameterized classes but thy are not. In this case the question is totally valid.

Answer (score 0):

You could use categorical equality.

```
class Category<T> {
    private Class<T> klazz;

    public Category(Class<T> klazz) {
        this.klazz = klazz;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return obj != null && klazz.equals(obj.getClass());
    }
}

System.out.println("#A : " + Collections.frequency(list, new Category(A.class)));
System.out.println("#B : " + Collections.frequency(list, new Category(B.class)));
```

(In Java 8 the solution will become more immediate.)